# EJB 3 with Swing

Tags: java, swing, ejb

I have a simple Eclipse project with EJB and web module.  I can access any bean from Servlet and this works fine.

What I would like to have is a Swing client.  I created a new Java Project, I added EJB module to the build path (along with Tomcat jars) so Swing client can see my beans and entities.

**My Question:** How can I run this project?  Standard Java Projects can't be run on server.

Comment: Swing means a graphical user interface. The typical way would be to have a `public static void main(String[] args)` method somewhere that initializes and start starts the graphical client.

Comment: In order to use EJB beans you have to run app server as well so simply running main method doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, but you are asking about the client. With EJB, there is a server, somewhere, sitting around, "hosting" your EJB layer. And you can have a client somewhere else. With Swing, we are talking about such a client. And then this client would be started as a completely standard Java application, connect to the server and then do the work by calling the apropriate methods on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of options. You could expose your EJB as a webservice and have your Swing application make webservice calls.

You could also use remote EJB invocation in your swing application. Am sure there are more options but the idea is to have your EJB application accessible from a remote client which will be your swing app.

Hope that helps